# Place tables side by side

Tags: html, css

The most elegant way to place tables side by side is enclose them inside a `<div>` and set it with CSS like this:

```
#div1 { 
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
}
```

But if I had 8 tables (I'm working with data so I have to use them) as I do? I have to write an id for each table?

Comment: You could always float them and give them a specific width.

Comment: You should use [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors) to share common styling.

Comment: Your question starts with a false statement... That is surely not even close to the most elegant or even elegant. Is your question, "Do I need to give each table an ID?" If so, the answer is "No, you do not."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `display: inline-table`, like this:

```
table {
    display: inline-table;
}
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VhPeP/1/